# Variável retornando valor nulo

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Eu estou criando um procedure para ele armazenar o nome do alimento na variável alimento do procedure, segue o código:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE armazena_nome(id INT, OUT alimento VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    SELECT alimentos_dados.nome_alimento INTO alimento FROM alimentos_dados WHERE alimentos_dados.id_alimento = id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Quando faço código abaixo após ter feito o "CALL" no procedure ele deveria retornar o nome do alimento mas retorna null:

```
SELECT @alimento
```

O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Comment: Coloque os passos que você criou e chamou esse procedimento?

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se você está chamando corretamente a procedure:

```
SET @id = 1;
CALL armazena_nome(@id,@alimento);
SELECT @alimento;
```